# Minimal grants for readonly single-table access on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Following is a list of commands that seems to work to create new user (login) and grant readonly access for one specified table on PostgreSQL.

Let's assume that these commands are executed on login with sufficient privileges (i.e. `postgres` login in default install).

```
CREATE ROLE user_name NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB 
NOCREATEROLE NOINHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD 'pwd' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

Now I want to grant `select` on table `tab_abc` on database `db_xyz`, so here it goes (database `db_xyz` is selected as current via PgAdmin or something like that):

```
grant select on tab_abc to user_name;
```

The question is: is this sufficient or there should be more grants (database `connect`, `usage` maybe)?

These commands seem to work for me, but my default installation has default security settings. What additional grants should I add if server admin configured stronger security?

It seems that I don't need to grant `connect` nor `usage` - are that implicite while granting `select`? Is it always so?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The question is: is this sufficient or there should be more grants
>   (database connect, usage maybe)?

Security may be hardened from the default mainly on these points:

- The `pg_hba.conf` file. It filters connections before any database privilege is considered. The default is relatively open for local connections, but it might be restricted to an explicit list of databases, usernames, and network origins.
- The permissions for **public**, the pseudo-role that anyone has. A user can implicitly connect only if the connect privilege is granted to `PUBLIC`. See [Created user can access all databases in PostgreSQL without any grants](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17790). A database might have all privileges revoked from public. See [REVOKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html) in the doc for the major PostgreSQL version you're using.
- The existence of the `public` schema. It's created with the database by default for convenience but it's not mandatory. Instead of removing public permissions from the `public` schema, it may make sense for DBAs to just drop the `public` schema when new users should have no implicit permission at all.

In the case when these defaults have been removed, to read one table a new user should be granted:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dbname TO username;
```

At the database level:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schemaname TO username;
GRANT SELECT ON schemaname.tablename TO username;
```