# Restrict Postgres roles by IP address outside of the pg_hba.conf file

Tags: mysql, postgresql, permissions

I am currently adding Postgres support to a deployment tool that currently only supports MySQL. This tool dynamically provisions and configures a database, among other things.

In MySQL, we can restrict users to a particular set of IP addresses, with SQL, as part of the grant command like so:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database_name.* TO 'my_user_name'@'192.168.101.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_secret_password'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database_name.* TO 'my_user_name'@'internal.example.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_secret_password'
```

In Postgres, it seems like the only way to set up a similar arrangement is to first create the user without restriction:

```
CREATE USER "my_user_name" WITH PASSWORD 'my_secret_password'
```

I've got it sorted out [how to then programmatically restrict this role to a particular database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17791/30762), but it seems like the only way to restrict the Postgres user by host is to create entries in the pg_hba.conf file.

This is problematic, as there are many users/hosts being created programmatically by an agent that does not have file-system access.

It looks like our only three options around this are to:

1. Manipulate the pg_hba.conf without using SQL to restrict a role, after it has been created using SQL
2. Allow "all", instead of particular users, for an allowed host
3. Restrict access to localhost only, and connect using a ssh tunnel

This seems less than ideal, and makes me wonder if I am overlooking an obvious solution. Is it possible to restrict Postgres roles by IP address using only SQL commands?

Comment: you can restrict postgres access by editing this file  pg_hba.conf

Comment: how many user will connect to server concurrent?

Comment: @a_vlad Probably only one, usually, but maybe several sometimes.

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna yes, thanks. I am seeking an alternate way, using pure SQL.

Comment: if only - I prefer restrict access by localhost only, and connect using ssh tunnel. may be it not exactly what You ask, but it not give additional loading to the server and work fine and secure.

Comment: @a_vlad that's a good idea, and one I had not thought of. I'm adding it as a third option, although a pure SQL solution would be preferential. Ideally, I can just translate a command, instead of adjusting existing infrastructure (although this would work for MySQL, as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this with native SQL in PostgreSQL. Also, Postgres manages the privileges and access in a very different way than MySQL.

I've built a VERY BASIC function (needs a lot of tweak and work around, specially handlers when the user already exists) that it adds straightly a user into the pg_hba file, create the user and grant the access to the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addRemoteUser(
  username text,
  iptarget text DEFAULT '0.0.0.0/0',
  dbtarget text DEFAULT 'all',
  passtext text DEFAULT 'CHANGEME',
  methodauth text DEFAULT 'md5')
  RETURNS boolean
AS $$
  import os
  hbaLine = "host " + str(dbtarget) + "\t" + str(username) + "\t" + str(iptarget) + "\t" + str(methodauth)
  createuser = "CREATE USER " + str(username) + " WITH PASSWORD '" + str(passtext) + "'"
  grantuser = "GRANT connect ON DATABASE " + str(dbtarget) + " TO " + str(username)
  hbaFilePath = plpy.execute("select setting from pg_settings where name = 'hba_file'", 1)
  hs = open(hbaFilePath[0]['setting'],"a")
  hs.write(hbaLine + "\n")
  addUserCommand = plpy.execute(createuser, 1)
  grantUserCommand = plpy.execute(grantuser, 1)
  reload = plpy.execute("select pg_reload_conf()", 1)
  hs.close()
  return True
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

(also posted [here](https://github.com/3manuek/postgres_scripts/blob/master/mysqlStyleGrantForPostgres.sql) on GitHub.)

Obviously is not for production yet, but at least you can have the rough idea how to build the function to do so. It needs PL/Python on the database for this particular example.

I know is not the ideal for this particular case, however I think it's a valid example on how to extend your Postgres installation.

Then, once the function is compiled, you can use SQL to call the function:

`SELECT addRemoteUser('mynewuser');`

Comment: Interesting approach... I half worried that this might be the case...

Comment: @BradWerth Another approach, which involves the user response, is to build a plpgsql (that language does not need any additional packages) which creates the user and prompts the line to be added in the pg_hba.conf (some of the queries in the original script can be reused).