# In PostgreSQL, how do I show the database privileges granted to public in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Below are the database privileges after I created a brand new database "foobar".

```
\l+ 
                                                    List of databases
  Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   |   Size    | Tablespace |                Description                 
----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------
foobar    | myuser   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 7233 kB   | pg_default | 
postgres  | myuser   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 7343 kB   | pg_default | default administrative connection database
template0 | rdsadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/rdsadmin          +| 7233 kB   | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
          |          |          |             |             | rdsadmin=CTc/rdsadmin |           |            | 
template1 | myuser   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/myuser            +| 7233 kB   | pg_default | default template for new databases
          |          |          |             |             | myuser=CTc/myuser     |           |            |
```

It has no access privileges listed, but I am able to connect to it with any user because apparently public is granted connect access to all databases, as shown in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17790/created-user-can-access-all-databases-in-postgresql-without-any-grants). After revoking connect from public on foobar, it shows the (accurate?) access privs.

```
 foobar    | myuser   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =T/myuser            +| 7233 kB   | pg_default | 
           |          |          |             |             | myuser=CTc/myuser     |           |            |
```

I assume this is done to make the output of `\l+` commands less verbose. I noticed that a similar thing happens with `\du`, when nothing is shown when a role has LOGIN but does show something for NOLOGIN.

Without full privileges listed explicitly, it is hard for a beginner like me to figure out what the 'effective' privileges is.

**So, question: how do I get commands like `\l+` to show the complete set of privileges?**

Comment: use `\z` to view grant table.,

Comment: You can refer this also., https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/auditing-users-and-roles-in-postgresql/

Comment: @SQLadmin it seems `\z` does not list the default privileges mentioned.